# Parity Syncing Forever? 1 block per second ???? is this the future of Blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, parity, parity-wallet

trying to sync parity wallet from last 30 days its taking forever to sync to the current Block Upto 4.4 Million blocks it took like 2-3 days but from then to 4.5 Million its taking like 1 Block/Sec still 1 Million Blocks to be synced do i need to wait 1000000 Seconds = 16,666 Minutes = 277 Hours = 11 days continuously or is there a ways u Blockchain guys developed ? please do help me in this?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Syncing the Ethereum Mainnet blockchain has been more and more complicated these days due to the size of it. The Ethereum clients such as Parity have come up with several ways to achieve what you need without having to wait too long. If all you want is to see the balance of your account and send ETH, for instance, one of these could help you:

- [Warp sync](https://wiki.parity.io/Warp-Sync.html) is the fact of downloading a snapshot of the state of the blockchain close to the top of the chain. Allowing you to be in sync quickly while verifying the rest of the chain in the background a posteriori. A flag in Parity v1.10 called `--warp-barrier` allows [you to specify a minimum block number to warp sync to](https://wiki.parity.io/FAQ-Basic-Operations,-Configuration,-and-Synchronization.html#why-is-warp-synchronization-so-fast).
- A [Light client](https://wiki.parity.io/Light-Client.html) will only download the block headers (not the body of the blocks) and allow you to sync much faster the whole blockchain. Note that you will not verify the blocks. To launch it, use the flag `--light`.

In both cases, you would need to erase the database of the blocks you've already downloaded using the command `parity db kill`.